# Как взаимодействовать с ботом Telegram

Tags: php, веб-программирование, telegram-bot

Создал бота, отправлял ему команды апишные из адресной строки браузера, он откликается. Как я понял, логика работы бота пишется в одном php файле, расположенном. Не могу понять как бот с этим файлом контактирует?  Там есть токен и адрес бота, но как инициализировать подключение к нему? На Java за меня все сделал Idea и спец. библиотека. Сейчас же мне надо все сделать на PHP. Я нашел много библиотек на PHP, но хочу понять на более простом примере как работает бот.

Answer (score 4):

1. Написать обработчик, к примеру:

```
//определим константы
define('BOT_TOKEN','ТВОЙТОКЕНДЛЯБОТА');
define('API_URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.BOT_TOKEN.'/');
//получаем информацию от бота
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
//расшифровываем её
$update = json_decode($content, true);
//ID чата с пользователем. Понадобится при отправке ответа
$chatID = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"]; 
//Текст сообщения от пользователя
$messageText = $update["message"]["text"];
//Имя пользователя (Пример: Игорь)
$username = $update["message"]["from"]["first_name"];
//Наш ответ
$reply = $username.", спасибо, что написали мне ".$messageText;
//Формируем запрос
$sendto = API_URL . "sendmessage?chat_id=" . $chatID . "&text=" . $reply;
//Отправляем запрос
file_get_contents($sendto);
```

2. Залить этот файл на какой-нибудь https сервер с поддержкой PHP (к примеру, heroku.com).
3. Привязать бота к твоему файлу (он должен быть на сервере с валидным сертификатом)
   набираешь в браузере:
   api.telegram.org/botТВОЙТОКЕНДЛЯБОТА/setWebhook?url=[https://ТВОЙСЕРВЕР.РУ/ТВОЙФАЙЛ.php](https://%D0%A2%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%99%D0%A1%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%92%D0%95%D0%A0.%D0%A0%D0%A3/%D0%A2%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%99%D0%A4%D0%90%D0%99%D0%9B.php)

Comment: Дополню что следует обратить на что сертификат : на домен или ИП адрес.